# Data printed on form duplicates when I switch accounts?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a profile page with blanks like username, city etc. I have successfully stored username & city in the MySQL Database using the `UPDATE` query. I have set the `WHERE` condition according to the email of the users. I have made 2 accounts with separates emails, for testing purposes. When I logged in from account #1, entered username & id, it was successfully stored in the correct row. Then I logged out, and logged in from account #2, and the username & city I entered in account #1 was **duplicated** and **printed on blanks of account #2**. **BUT in database**, the data was still distinguished until I pressed ENTER. So my question is, why is this happening and how do I fix this?

**Action.php:**

```
<?php
session_start(); //---> start session
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'id1753243_venom', 'roushan123', 'id1753243_gameware_01');
if(!$con)
{
    echo 'Not connected to the server';
}

$city = $_SESSION['city'];
$city = $_POST['city'];

if(isset($_POST['username']))
if(isset($_POST['city']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET username='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username)."', city = '$city' WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_SESSION['email'])."‌​'";
    $insert = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username; //---> this will store username into session variable
    $_SESSION['city'] = $city; //---> this will store city into session variable
}

if(!$insert)
{
    echo 'Not inserted';
}
else
{
    echo 'Inserted';
}
header("refresh:2; url=user.php");
?>
```

**And this is the user.php:**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

/* Displays user information and some useful messages */
session_start();
include 'db.php';

// Check if user is logged in using the session variable
if ( $_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 ) {
  $_SESSION['message'] = "You must log in before viewing your profile page!";
  header("location: error.php");    
}
else {
    // Makes it easier to read
    $first_name = $_SESSION['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_SESSION['last_name'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $active = $_SESSION['active'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $city = $_SESSION['city'];

}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.ico">

    <title>Social Junction | User Profile</title>

    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />


    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS     -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Animation library for notifications   -->
    <link href="assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!--  Light Bootstrap Table core CSS    -->
    <link href="assets/css/light-bootstrap-dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <!--  CSS for Demo Purpose, don't include it in your project     -->
    <link href="assets/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="assets/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar" data-color="blue" data-image="http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/originals/2015/Creative_Wallpaper_Set_of_business_people_100390_.jpg">

    <!--   you can change the color of the sidebar using: data-color="blue | azure | green | orange | red | purple" -->


        <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
          <div class="pic"></div>
            <div class="logo">
                 <a href="#">
                    <span style="font-size: 28px;">Hello <span style="font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $first_name.' '.$last_name; ?>!</span></span>
                    </a>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="dashboard.php">
                        <i class="pe-7s-graph"></i>
                        <p>Dashboard</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="user.html">
                        <i class="pe-7s-user"></i>
                        <p>User Profile</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-panel">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-example-2">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Profile</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                                    <b class="caret"></b>
                                    <span class="notification">5</span>
                              </a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Notification 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Notification 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Notification 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Notification 4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another notification</a></li>
                              </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                           <a href="">
                               Account
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    Dropdown
                                    <b class="caret"></b>
                              </a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                              </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.php">
                                Log out
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="header">
                                <h4 class="title">Edit Profile</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <form method="POST" action="action.php">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-5">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Company (disabled)</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled placeholder="Company" value="Creative Code Inc.">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Username</label>
                                                <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>First Name</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Company" value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Last Name</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $last_name; ?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Address</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Home Address" value="Bld Mihail Kogalniceanu, nr. 8 Bl 1, Sc 1, Ap 09">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>City</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['city']; ?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Country</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="country" class="form-control" placeholder="Country" value="Andrew">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Postal Code</label>
                                                <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="ZIP Code">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>About Me</label>
                                                <textarea name="aboutme" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Here can be your description" value="Mike">Lamborghini Mercy, Your chick she so thirsty, I'm in that two seat Lambo.</textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right">Update Profile</button>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </form>
                       </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card card-user">
                            <div class="image">
                                <img src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1431578500526-4d9613015464?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=300&q=75&w=400" alt="..."/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="author">
                                     <a href="#">
                                    <img class="avatar border-gray" src="assets/img/faces/face-3.jpg" alt="..."/>

                                      <h4 class="title"><?php echo $first_name; ?><br />
                                         <small><?php echo $username; ?></small>
                                      </h4>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <p class="description text-center"> "Lamborghini Mercy <br>
                                                    Your chick she so thirsty <br>
                                                    I'm in that two seat Lambo"
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <button href="#" class="btn btn-simple"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></button>
                                <button href="#" class="btn btn-simple"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></button>
                                <button href="#" class="btn btn-simple"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square"></i></button>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <nav class="pull-left">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Home
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Company
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Portfolio
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                               Blog
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <p class="copyright pull-right">
                    &copy; 2016 <a href="http://www.creative-tim.com">Creative Tim</a>, made with love for a better web
                </p>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </div>
</div>


</body>

    <!--   Core JS Files   -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--  Checkbox, Radio & Switch Plugins -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-checkbox-radio-switch.js"></script>

    <!--  Charts Plugin -->
    <script src="assets/js/chartist.min.js"></script>

    <!--  Notifications Plugin    -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>

    <!--  Google Maps Plugin    -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <!-- Light Bootstrap Table Core javascript and methods for Demo purpose -->
    <script src="assets/js/light-bootstrap-dashboard.js"></script>

    <!-- Light Bootstrap Table DEMO methods, don't include it in your project! -->
    <script src="assets/js/demo.js"></script>


</html>
```

I know the code is not secure, this is just for test purposes. Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: One question: why do you execute
`$city = $_SESSION['city'];
$city = $_POST['city'];`
before `if(isset($_POST['city']))`.

Second, and this is just an advice, try to use prepared statements when using SQL queries.

Comment: I was editing it just now.

Comment: The amount of problems in your code is kinda overwhelming. `$city = $_SESSION['city']; $city = $_POST['city'];` <-- Why? You are effectively overwriting the `$city` variable, making the first one completely pointless. `if(isset($_POST['username']))` <-- no opening bracket on a multiline body. `$_SESSION['email']` <-- did you destroy sessions on logout? `header("refresh:2; url=user.php");` <-- headers cannot be sent after output `echo 'Not inserted'; echo 'Inserted';` <-- output. I haven't even checked the rest of your code yet.

Comment: I'm pretty much beginning to learn PHP, can you show me how my action.php should look like? It would really help!